# DAX for MAX of a group

Tags: visual-studio-2012, max, powerpivot, calculated-columns, dax

I have two data columns:

```
Record | Record Version
------------------------
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 1
2      | 2
2      | 3
2      | 4
3      | 1
3      | 2
3      | 3
4      | 1
4      | 2
4      | 3
4      | 4
4      | 5
4      | 6
5      | 1
6      | 1
```

Is it possible to create a calculated column within a MVS-2012 model or PowerPivot that will give the MAX of the `Record Version` for a corresponding `Record`? For example the MAX value of `Record 1` is 3, MAX value of `Record 2` is 4 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, as @mmarie suggests, you are better dealing with this kind of problem with a measure rather than a calculated column. That said, sometimes you just need that extra column (usually to use as a dimension).

Assuming you have a table called `recordsFact`, this gives the MAX of that record:

```
= CALCULATE(MAX(recordsFact[Record Version]), 
             FILTER(recordsFact, recordsFact[Record] = EARLIER(recordsFact[Record])
                   ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Add that table to your Power Pivot model, either by pasting the data into Excel and then clicking Add to Data Model on the Power Pivot ribbon, or by opening the Power Pivot Window and adding it form it's original source there.

1. In the Power Pivot window, go to the table where this data is located.
2. Select the Record Version column, then click the drop-down next to AutoSum in the Calculations group on the Home tab and choose Max.
   [image]
3. A calculated column will appear at the bottom. YOu can rename it to something like Max Record Version.
4. Make a PivotTable in Excel (click the PivotTable button on the Home tab).
5. Add the Record field to rows and the Max Record Version to values.

[image]

If you actually want a calculation that will give you the max for the group of record you could do something like:

```
=SUMX(VALUES(Table1[Record])
      ,CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Record Version]))
     )
```

Comment: I added the SUMX calculation to MVS and it only returns the same number in the Record Version column.

Comment: I also tried adding the MAX measure to PowerPivot and the MAX of record version column also only returns the same Record Version. 

Any suggestions?